# Algorithm to resove the offset between unpaired 2d coordinates (better in Python)?

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing

Suppose I have matrix A represents 2d coordinates:

```
x_A = [1, 3, 5, 9]
y_A = [1, 2, 4, 10]
```

And I apply the following transformation (offset) to get matrix B':

```
x_B' = x_A + p + some_small_noise
y_B' = y_A + q + some_small_noise

e.g. for p = 0.1, q = -0.1, ignore the noise, we have 

x_B' = [1.1, 3.1, 5.1, 9.1]
y_B' = [0.9, 1.9, 3.9, 9.9]
```

The I randomize the order of pairs of coordinates to get B:

```
x_B = [3.1, 9.1, 5.1, 1.1]
y_B = [1.9, 9.9, 3.9, 0.9]
```

The question is then, by knowing A and B, how to get the original offset p and q?

It ought to have some algorithm for doing this, but I couldn't get the right keyword for googling.

Answer (score 3):

```
x_b=[3.1, 9.1, 5.1, 1.1]
x_b=sorted(x_b)
p=x_b[0]-x_a[0]
```

simillary to q also

Comment: This is only valid when the distance of sorted x array less then the small_noise there might be have. I actually is looking for a more robust way that can deal with such noisy case

Comment: But anyway, this is prompt and nice. I actually hadn't thought about such a simple sort yet. Thank you

Comment: @user1824372 do u have any formula to find noise

Comment: OK, I think I can sort y as well. in that case I can get the mode(the most frequent number) out of the difference between two sorted matrix to exclude any mis-identified pair, assume the chance of such mis-identified pair is small and only have local effect

Comment: @user1824372 if u feel answer is right tick. if u still want any thing comment me i will do.its way i can learn

Comment: the noise is presumably Gaussian

Comment: @user1824372 i am little lo in statics or math . if u have certain formula to find PG . we can implement here

Comment: That is only valid if there is no noise, or by pure chance. However, the sorting does seem to be a good choice. You just didn't take things far enough. See my answer for more, specifically the "Edit" section. I don't think you can get the exact value of p and q.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be ignoring the noise, but rather including it in the calculations. One solution is to try to put a bound on the noise, call it k. The problem can thus be thought of as:

```
x_B' = x_A + p + x, where -k <= x <= k
y_B' = y_A + q + x, where -k <= x <= k
```

The issue of course is that the actual value of p and q are obscured by the noise, for that reason I'm thinking you can only approximate what the value of p and q are. The goal is then to find the values for p and q where k is minimized. An extension of Sundar Nataraj's answer leads to the following O(N log N) solution in Python.

```
x_b = sorted(x_b) # Ensure x_b is in sorted order
y_b = sorted(y_b) # Ensure y_b is in sorted order
dx = [x_b[i] - x_a[i] for i in range(len(x_b)] # Obtain the x differences
dy = [y_b[i] - y_a[i] for i in range(len(y_b)] # Obtain the y differences
dx_range = (min(dx), max(dx)) # Find the x difference range
dy_range = (min(dy), max(dy)) # Find the y difference range
p = sum(dx_range) / 2.0 # Minimize k_x by making p the middle of the x range
q = sum(dy_range) / 2.0 # Minimize k_y by making q the middle of the y range

# Optionally, the k values can be calculated as well:
k_x = dx_max - p # Calculate k for x values
k_y = dy_max - q # Calculate k for y values
k = max(k_x,k_y) # Max of the dimensional k values is the actual k value
```

This appears to be an optimal solution for minimizing k_x and k_y. However, note that p and q are actually within the below ranges:

```
dx_min <= p <= dx_max
dy_min <= q <= dy_max
```

That being said, I'm thinking that statistically speaking, p and q *should* be rather close to the calculated values with fairly high probability.

Edit:
Another look at Sundar Nataraj's answer got me thinking and it seemed like another way to estimate p and q would be to simply set them as the mean of the differences (extended from the original Python code). It doesn't change the range of values for p and q, but I think it leads to a more accurate estimation of p and q, since the actual min and max differences may be excessively high or low biasing excessively towards one side or the other.

```
p = sum(dx) / len(dx)
q = sum(dy) / len(dy)
```

Comment: +1 i belive u have given good explantion than me. much thing to learn from u. i intended is sto show him the way how can he able to do. not to give him full code. he has to try and learn

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ: If that is your intent, then it's probably better (in my opinion) to do it as a comment rather than giving it as an answer, especially given the length of your answer and that it doesn't really take into account the noise. I gave the code because otherwise I would have given the equations and when it comes to Python, there barely any difference between the Python code and the mathematical equations for something like this. User was fairly close by looking for the mode though.

Comment: Thank you a lot for these answers. I've learned a lot indeed.